# Redis hash vs key hierarchy

Tags: redis

What's the practical difference between keeping data in multiple hashes (`HSET foo oof 1`, `HSET bar rab 2`) and using plain keys in a hierarchy (`SET foo:oof 1`, `SET bar:rab 2`)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the manual](https://redis.io/docs/data-types/#hashes), you'd use hashes to represent a single object.

Also, it's not that efficient to iterate over Redis keys, so if you need to get all the data from a single object, `HGETALL` is your friend, not a `KEYS thing:10:*`/multiget fiasco.

However, you can't e.g. set expiry for only one key of a hash, so if you need that functionality, you'll want to use regular keys.

Comment: FYI - HGETALL can be is as bad as KEYS if the hash is big enough

Comment: Also, keys require more RAM overhead compared to fields in a hashes

Comment: "Also, keys require more RAM overhead compared to fields in a hashes", which can get substantial